# How do I combine this update delete and select query into one?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert, sql-delete

- I am trying to implement the functionality of a password reset page.
- User gets a token which is stored in the database
- When the user tries to update the password, I want to do the following things
- Check if token is present and has not expired and get user id for such token
- Update this user id to change password
- Delete the token for this user id IF update was SUCCESSFUL

This is what I was able to come up with as 3 separate queries

```
SELECT user_id FROM reset_tokens WHERE token = $1 AND now() < expires
UPDATE users SET password=$1 WHERE user_id=$2 RETURNING user_id
DELETE FROM reset_tokens WHERE user_id=$1
```

How do I combine these into 1 query? Thank you for the suggestions

The delete doesnt happen if there was no update executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CTEs:

```
    WITH s as (
          SELECT user_id
          FROM reset_tokens
          WHERE token = $1 AND now() < expires
         ),
         u as (
          UPDATE users
              SET password = $1
              WHERE user_id = $2
              RETURNING user_id
        ),
        d as (
         DELETE FROM reset_tokens
             WHERE user_id = $1
        )
SELECT *
FROM s;
```

Comment: the update and delete are not getting triggered no?